# Facebook Authentication using Tornado and Angular2

Tags: python, facebook, authentication, angular, tornado

So I am trying to work on my own application, and trying to get authentication working via facebook. I dont want to have the credentials on UI side, so want to put all the authentication logic on the server side.

Basically my authentication in tornado looks like:

```
class AuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        my_url = (self.request.protocol + "://" + self.request.host +
                  "/auth/facebook?next=" +
                  tornado.escape.url_escape(self.get_argument("next", "/")))
        if self.get_argument("code", False):
            self.get_authenticated_user(
                redirect_uri=my_url,
                client_id="id",
                client_secret="secret",
                code=self.get_argument("code"),
                callback=self._on_auth)
            return
        self.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri=my_url,
                                client_id="id",
                                extra_params={"scope": "public_profile,user_friends,email"})
```

I have written an angular2 service which is calling this api in tornado, to do authentication.

```
  signMeIn(){
this.http.get('/auth/facebook')
.map(res => res.text())
.subscribe(
  data => this.user = data
  console.log("success")
  ,
  err => console.log("Error Authenticating User"),
  () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
);
```

}

But I am getting this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?...response_type=code&client_id=id. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

I have this in my base handler as well.

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def get_current_user(self):
    return self.get_secure_cookie("user")
def set_default_headers(self):
    print "setting headers!!!"
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
```

Please advice

Comment: You have to redirect the user to the URL.

Comment: I know I am doing something stupid. Which URL? My tornado url is /auth/facebook. Which url do you mean? are you saying i cannot have it in an angular service?

Comment: Read the Facebook login documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, my authentication from facebook and tornado is working perfectly ok. My issue is i want to grab the user token, and save it in the browser. Hence I was trying to implement it an angularservice. Make a http get call, and the response will get me the token. So what I want to do is, user click a login button - > makes a call to tornado via an angular service - > tornado does a redirect and grabs the user token - > responds back to the angular2 service -> angular2 service saves the cookie in the localstorage, and hence next time the UI dosent ask the user to authenticate.

Comment: You can not request the login dialog URL in the background – you need to redirect the user’s browser to it.